# Convex set which is not connected

Tags: general-topology

I know that in $\mathbb{R}^n$ a convex set is connected, but is this true for other spaces (or metrics)? Is there an example of a convex set which is not connected?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In any topological vector space any convex set is connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any normed (even topological) vector space (finite dimensional or not) $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$ a convex set is defined as any subset $A\subseteq V$ such that for any $v,w\in A$ and any $t\in[0,1]$ the intermediate point $tv+(1-t)w$ belongs to $A$.

This gives us a formula for a path $\lambda:[0,1]\to V$ connecting $v,w\in A$, namely $\lambda(t)=tv+(1-t)w$. The only remaining thing is whether $\lambda$ is continuous? It is, since vector addition and multiplication by scalar are.

Thus any convex subset is not only connected, but even path connected.

---

Outside of topological vector spaces convexity can be defined in multiple, non-equivalent ways. There is even a purely abstract "convexity space" term, [see wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set#Generalizations_and_extensions_for_convexity). However most of them will remain connected, e.g. [geodesic convexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_convexity). But not all, e.g. convexity inside $\mathbb{Q}$ with respect to the natural order.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! While reading your answer (and the other ones) I realized that I may have expressed myself wrong. So now I wonder if it is possible to talk about convexity in a not normed space. And moreover if it is possible to find a convex set which is **not** connected? I'm asking this because I read that in general "convex" and "connected" are independend concepts. Am I wrong?

Comment: It's all more clear now, thanks! And it's far more complex than I thought (I'm a first year student and we rarely work with non Euclidean spaces).

Answer (score 1):

Take two points $x$ and $y$ in your convex set $E$. By convexity, the segment line joining $x$ to $y$ is included in $E$, therefore there is a path joining $x$ to $y$.

So $E$ is path connected, so it is connected.

Answer (score 0):

If $C$ is a  convex set in a topological vector space then $f(t)=(1-t)x+ty$ defines  a continuous map from $[0,1]$ to $C$ with $f(0)=x$ and $f(1)=y$. Hence $C$ is path connected. Any path connected space is connected.